# How to pass host's environment variables as args to Docker Compose using a .env file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to pass some host's environment variables content as args to the docker-compose file, through a .env file. But the variable is interpreted as a string.

Follows the content of my files:

**.env:**

```
USER=$USER
UID=$UID
GID=$GID
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "2"

services:
    opencv_python:
        build:
            args:
                - username=${USER}
                - uid=${UID}
                - gid=${GID}
            context: .
            dockerfile: opencv_base.Dockerfile
        container_name: ocv-data-augmentation
        image: ocv-data-augmentation
        environment: 
            DISPLAY: $DISPLAY
            QT_X11_NO_MITSHM: 1
        volumes: 
            - "../project:/home/&{USER}/data_augmentation/" # Host : Container
            - "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix"
        tty: true
```

**And this is the output of the command `docker-compose config`:**

```
 services:
  opencv_python:
    build:
      args:
        gid: $$GID
        uid: $$UID
        username: fsalvagnini
      context: /home/fsalvagnini/Documents/containers/data_augmentation/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: opencv_base.Dockerfile
    container_name: ocv-data-augmentation
    environment:
      DISPLAY: :1
      QT_X11_NO_MITSHM: 1
    image: ocv-data-augmentation
    tty: true
    volumes:
    - /home/fsalvagnini/Documents/containers/data_augmentation/project:/home/&{USER}/data_augmentation:rw
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
version: '2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the .env file and assuming that all the env variables are defined, you just need to follow one step:

> **.env file**

```
source .env
```

The above statement will source all the variables defined in `.env` and hence the env variables will be accessible to docker-compose.

Just added thing, you should also look at `${VARIABLE:-default}` just in case you need to pass a default value.

More documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)

Comment: Even when I executed `source .env` before the `docker-compose config` command the same result was achieved (gid as $$GID and uid as $$UID).

Comment: Hey @Felipe the env substitution is indeed working, if you see the username and display vars. Now I believe you want to map your host machine uid and gid to container. But you need to understand that the same might not exists in container under /etc/passwd/ and /etc/group/. Also understand that this will have different behaviour on different host machine. You can further read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docker-compose manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

> When you set the same environment variable in multiple files, here’s
>   the priority used by Compose to choose which value to use:
>
> 1. Compose file
> 2. Shell environment variables
> 3. Environment file
> 4. Dockerfile
> 5. Variable is not defined

So if shell environment variables are not set, then env file will be used.

For your case, if you need to use shell env vars, you don't need to create `.env` file. To solve your issue, you need to export the variables before invoking `docker-compose`.

```
export GID
export UID
export DISPLAY
docker-compose config
```

output:

```
services:
  opencv_python:
    build:
      args:
        gid: '20'
        uid: '501'
        username: enix
      context: /Users/enix/source/devops/stackoverflow
      dockerfile: opencv_base.Dockerfile
    container_name: ocv-data-augmentation
    environment:
      DISPLAY: :1
      QT_X11_NO_MITSHM: 1
    image: ocv-data-augmentation
    tty: true
    volumes:
    - /Users/enix/source/devops/project:/home/&{USER}/data_augmentation:rw
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
version: '2.0'
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly. There is a way that I can embed the export commands inside de docker-compose.yml?

Comment: no, if don't export the env var before calling docker-compse, docker-compose will not be able to get those variables. or you can call docker-compse like that `UID=$UID GID=$GID DISPLAY=$DISPLAY docker-compose config`